# Angular Bootstrap datepicker implement

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I want to integrate Angular datepicker in my system.

I have already done from [this url](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1198/angularjs-bootstrap-datepicker-enable-disable-dates-with-configuration-example) . But is there any option for that we can add module and we can use by parameters?

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer? Do you want to make a custom directive? Do you want to have a separate module for the date-picker? What is your goal?

Comment: I want to make separate module